# text size limitation in PgAdmin query

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to get the source code of a function in my db.
I run this query:

```
select proname,prosrc from pg_proc where...
```

However when I copy the data in the `procsrc` field it copy only some of the function code, the whole code is not shown. I suspect that somewhere in the preference there is a text size limit.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Show the table schema.

Answer (score 1):

[**Character Types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html)

Text type has unlimited length. There are another problem.

Or try to change **Max characters per column** option.
*File > Options > Query Tool > Max. characters per column*

> Max characters per column - Use the Max characters per column field to
>   specify the maximum length of data displayed in a single column.

Comment: i gave there value of 100000000000000 and it still doesnt show all

Comment: @user3754582: -1 for infinite length.